# How to publish a workspace crate with a submodule dependency?

Tags: git, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have a project that consist in two crates in a **workspace**, one of them `crate-sys` generates some bindings. The other, `crate` consumes that `crate-sys` and builds a proper rust API on top of it.
On the toplevel git project (workspace), I have configured a gitsubmole that downloads the original code to build the bindings (for `crate-sys`). It downloads the code to a `vendor` folder inside the `crate-sys` crate.

```
[Workspace]
    - crate-sys
        - vendor
    - crate
```

Now the problem comes on:
How to publish `crate-sys` to crates.io so it will download the `vendor` code as well? Since the submodule information comes from the workspace git root not the crate itself?

Comment: [rdkafka-sys](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/tree/master/rdkafka-sys) seems like a good example. Essentially: `cargo publish` won't know that there is a submodule. It will just include all the files from there. Which is good, because crates should contain all the source necessary to be compiled and not require any additional downloads.

Comment: @Caesar, well, that makes sense and in that case I do not have to change anything since it will be distributed. thats awesome!, Can you add it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Caesar: Your comment should be an answer, me thinks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cargo publish` won't check whether there is a submodule. It will just include all the files from below the current crate (package, actually?) folder except `target/`.
Which is good, because crates should contain all the source necessary to be compiled and not require any additional downloads.

However, cargo does exclude subfolders in some situations (e.g. if they contain a `Cargo.toml`), so if in doubt, you can construct the `.crate` file and check its contents before publishing.

```bash
cargo package --allow-dirty # This won't publish, just create the .crate file
tar tvf ../target/package/*.crate
```